# Please explain this behaviour

Tags: json, linq-to-sql, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a function that goes like this:

```
IEnumerable<News> articles = _repository.GetLatestNews();

foreach (News news in articles) {
    news.IsFetched = true;
    _repository.Save();
}
return Json(articles, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Which does not return any json data (and I'm sure there should be some output, because I can debug inside the foreach loop).

When I change the code to the following:

```
IEnumerable<News> articles = _repository.GetLatestNews();
var jsonArticles = articles.ToList();

foreach (News news in articles) {
    news.IsFetched = true;
}
_repository.Save();

return Json(jsonArticles, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

I get the desired output.

Now I'm curious, why does this happen? What's the reason for this behavior?

Comment: Is `articles` populated when you set a break point at the `return` statement?

Comment: This must be independent of JSON and MVC then. My guess would be that the result of GetLatestNews() from linq2sql is an enumerable that fires a query whenever you enumerate it. In the foreach you change the items in a way that they are excluded from the query result afterwards. When you call the JSON serializer that enumerates the IEnumerable again, fires a query again, and gets a different result that time. If you call ToList() it loads the data into an in-memory list, and you can enumerate it as many time as you want without running a query again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is this line:

```
var jsonArticles = articles.ToList();
```

that actually forces the query to execute and eagerly fetch the data. There won't be any result returned until you start enumerate the enumerable returned by the `GetLatestNews` method.